# How to use declared c++ variable inside bison grammar

Tags: c++, bison

I am trying to keep an error count in a variable called 'mismatches', in which i declare in the first part of the bison file.

In my bison grammar, i set a value to that variable.

Then in the 3rd part of the bison file, in the main() function i cout its value, and it's 0.

A very modified/cut down version of my bison file:

```
%{
extern "C" FILE *yyin;
extern int yylineno;
extern int yynerrs;

int yylex();

// Declare 'mismatches'
int mismatches;

%}

%error-verbose


%%

expression:
          expression ADDOP term
          {
                     cout << "Parser is now here. Going to set `mismatches` to 6";
                     mismatches = 6;
          }
          | term
          ;

%%

int  main()
{         
          // Outputs 0
          cout << mismatches;

          yyparse();

          return 1;

}
```

What should i do so that the variable 'mismatches' can be used in all parts of the bison file?

Comment: It already is. Look at the generated file, the complete block between `%{` and `%}` is copied as-is to the resulting file, and it should be early in the generated file as well (otherwise there might be problems with including header files).

Comment: Indeed I do see it there. And from what I see, it should be working as intended. But its value is 0. Even if i don't assign it a value, just have `int mismatches;` and try to cout << mismatches; in the main() function, it says 0 (when it should give me an uninitialized warning)

Comment: Not for global variables as they are implicitly initialized. See e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/7280/) for a quote from Bjarne Stroutrup (the creator of C++).

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure that the parser rule is executed?

Comment: Yes. Very informative quote, thanks for that. And, the problem is that i was using cout << mismatches << " string ". so i was always getting "0string". human error =(  thanks for the concern though. i +1'd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to output the variable after you run the parser, like so

```
int  main()
{         
      yyparse();
      cout << mismatches;

      return 1;
}
```

Comment: coincidentally, i just about ran into this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count *syntax* errors, an obvious place to insert your counter update is yyerror.

Also, you should *not* use

```
%{
int counter;
%}
```

as you will get as many copies of "counter" as you have files including your header.  If you display "counter" from another file, then it's no surprise you display 0, since you display *another* variable named counter.

Provided you use Bison (and recent enough), you'd rather do something like this:

```
%code provides
{
  extern int counter;

}
%code
{
  int counter;
}
```

Alternatively, use `%{...%}` to declare it (i.e., with `extern`), and define it (i.e., without `extern`) *after* the second `%%`.